# Determine whether an object is on heap or stack programmatically

Tags: c#, stack, heap-memory

Is it possible to write a generic method which determines if a variable's memory is on heap or on stack? Such method gets a variable as an argument and return a `bool` and can be useful to check if a fixed statement is necessary.

Comment: You do realize that passing it to a method means that the method tests the parameter rather than the original variable...

Comment: @RaymondChen how if the argument is a reference or a pointer?

Comment: The printer or reference is on the stack. The thing it points to is another story. But you should just fix the object regardless. The stack is an implementation detail.

Comment: I'm curious why you care

Comment: @Flydog57 Instead of checking details I'll just check it using a method. stack objects don't move and you can have a pointer to their address.

Comment: You're probably going down the wrong road here. If you need something locked at a particular memory location, then explicitly lock it there. In that case, your program *knows* that its location is fixed, and you can treat it specially. Otherwise, your code shouldn't care. Writing general-purpose code that acts differently based on where in memory something lives sounds like a fast path to madness. What specific problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: @JimMischel I'm not writing professional codes. I thought there may be a way to implement the memory location selection rules described in C# tutorials programmatically just out of curiosity. It may or may not be useful in professional programs.

Comment: I think it may be useful to determine if a fixed statement is needed. using a fixed statement for stack variables is impossible and for heap variables is necessary.